# Selecting lists from lists of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
points = Tuples[Range[0, 1.25, 0.25], 9]
```

I would like to select only those lists who have  the following properties, naming the elements of each lists with slots:

- 1) `#1>0.4`
- 2) `#9>#8,#8>#7,#7>#6`
- 3) `#1+#2+#3< 1.22`
- 4) `#5<#4`
- 5) `#4<1.21`
- 6) `0.5 (#1 (2.42-#6+#7)+#2(#4+1.21-#6)+#3 (#5+#4))<0.625`
- 7) `All #>0`

Any suggestions to do this?

**UPDATE**

As Rashid pointed out, this is terribly slow to solve. If any brilliant lad can think of a way to directly construct such a list, chapeau!

In the spirit of making the code less slow as suggested by Rashid, I have written this code for the first list of lists:

```
points = Partition[#, 9] &@
   Flatten@Tuples[{Tuples[Range[0.25, 0.75, 0.25], 1], 
      Tuples[Range[0, 0.75, 0.25], 4], 
      Tuples[Range[0, Pi/3, Pi/12], 4]}];
```

Please use this code instead of the first. With this code condition 1 is implicitly given. Any other suggestions for building the list is welcomed.  I also added some extra conditions to limit the length of this list.

Comment: You can drop condition 7 as well by starting the second inner `Tuples` at `0.25` and the third at `Pi/12`.

Comment: Yeah, yet I just realized that the code I wrote then mixes the order of the elements of each list. This is not what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** for applying all test simultaneously.

There do not appear to be any lists that simultaneously satisfy all seven conditions.

```
oneSelectTests = MapAt[Function[{f}, f[Sequence @@ #] &], ;; -2]@tests;
oneSelectRes = Select[And @@ Through[oneSelectTests[#]] &]@points;
Dimensions@oneSelectRes
(* {0} *)
```

---

A solution with `Slot`.

```
tests = {
         #1 > 0.4 &, 
         And @@ {#9 > #8, #8 > #7, #7 > #6} &, 
         #1 + #2 + #3 < 1.22 &, 
         #5 < #4 &, #4 < 1.21 &, 
         0.5 (#1 (2.42 - #6 + #7) + #2 (#4 + 1.21 - #6) + #3 (#5 + #4)) < 0.625 &, 
         And @@ Positive[#] &
        }
```

Then build the set of `Select` functions that take each sublist as its list of parameters. The last test is not mapped as it needs to take the list.

```
selTests = Select /@ MapAt[Function[{f}, f[Sequence @@ #] &], ;; -2]@tests;
```

Then apply the `selTests` to `points`.

```
res = Through@selTests@points;
Dimensions /@ res

(* {{6718464, 9}, {116640, 9}, {1632960, 9}, {4199040, 9}, 
    {8398080, 9}, {1292004, 9}, {1953125, 9}} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Edmund, thank you for your suggestion. Does your code consider all the conditions together? I need all conditions to be considered.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted 7 separate sets to each condition. Misread. Let me think about that.

Comment: @MirkoAveta See update. There do not appear to be any list that simultaneously satisfy all conditions.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. I must firstly say that the first condition has been suppressed, as I have said in Rashed's reply update. I will see if this happens also in the new definition of 'points'.

Answer (score 4):

```
points = Tuples[Range[0, 1.25, 0.25], 9];

pnts1b = Select[points, #[[1]] > 0.4 &]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 11.617923

`Pick` instead of `Select` is faster:

```
pnts1a = Pick[points, UnitStep[points[[All, 1]] - .4], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.545490

As suggested by @Rashid, using the conditions upfront is much faster:

```
pnts1c = Tuples[{Select[Range[0, 1.25, .25], # > .4 &], 
        ## & @@ (ConstantArray[Range[0, 1.25, 0.25], 8])}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.126385

**Update:** constructing tuples bottom up using the conditions

In the following the list `cxyz` stands for a list of tuples satisfying conditions `x`, `y` and `z`. Since conditions 1, 3 and 7 relate to entries `1,2,3` and conditions `4,5,7` to entries `4` and `5`, and conditions `2,7` apply to entries `6,7,8,9` we can piece together 9-tuples from 3-tuples satisying conditions `1,2,7` and, 2-tuples satisfying conditions `4,5,7` and 4-tuples satisfying conditions `2,7`. Then we can filter the resulting list of 9-tuples using condition 6.

```
AbsoluteTiming[c137 = Pick[tt = Tuples[{Range[.5, 1.25, .25], Range[.25, 1.25, .25], 
      Range[.25, 1.25, .25]}], Total[#] < 1.22 & /@ tt];
 c457 = Partition[Flatten[Table[{j, i}, {j, .25, 1.0, .25}, {i, .25, j - .25, .25}]], 2];
 c13457 = Join @@@ Tuples[{c137, c457}];
 c27 = Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, .25, 1.25, .25}, 
   {j, i + .25, 1.25, .25}, {k, j + .25, 1.25, .25}, {l, k + .25, 1.25, .25}]],  4];
 c123457 = Join @@@ Tuples[{c13457, c27}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally checking for condition 6, we get an empty set as the final result

```
Pick[c123457, 0.5 (#[[1]] (2.42 - #[[6]] + #[[7]]) + #[[2]] (#[[4]] + 
          1.21 - #[[6]]) + #[[3]] (#[[5]] + #[[4]])) < 0.625 & /@ c123457]
```

> {}

Incidentally, identifying 9-tuples satisfying condition 6 only takes a long time:

```
lengthc6 = Length[Pick[tuples, 0.5 (#[[1]] (2.42 - #[[6]] + #[[7]]) + #[[2]] (#[[4]] + 
    1.21 - #[[6]]) + #[[3]] (#[[5]] + #[[4]])) < 0.625 & /@ tuples]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {89.781723, 1292004}

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I didn't know that Pick was that faster!!

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a direct approach using `Select` with Part(`[[]]`) and Slot (`#`)**, but given the size of `points`, this will definitely be very slow. Each selection takes 2-3 minutes to run on my computer for a total of ~20 minutes:

```
points = Tuples[Range[0, 1.25, 0.25], 9];
points1 = Select[points, #[[1]] > 0.25 &]
points2 = Select[points, #[[9]] > #[[8]] && #[[8]] > #[[7]] && #[[7]] > #[[6]] &]
points3 = Select[points, #[[1]] + #[[2]] + #[[3]] < 1.22 &]
points4 = Select[points, #[[5]] < #[[4]] &]
points5 = Select[points, #[[4]] < 1.21 &]
points6 = Select[points,  0.5 (#[[1]] (2.42 - #[[6]] + #[[7]]) + #[[2]] (#[[4]] + 1.21 - #[[6]]) + #[[3]] (#[[5]] + #[[4]])) < 0.625 &]
points7 = Select[points, Apply[Times, #] > 0 &]
```

Note that `points7` assumes all numbers are either zero or positive. A more generally implementation would be something like `points7b = Select[points, Min[Sign[#]] > 0 &]`

Since the tuples list in `points` is so large, **I suspect you would be better off just constructing the final lists you want**. For example, using `points7=Tuples[Range[0.25,1.25,0.25],9]` rather than selecting the ones without zeros.

**Edit -by Mirko Aveta**

In the spirit of making the code less slow as suggested by Rashid, I have written this code for the first list of lists:

```
points = Partition[#, 8] &@
   Flatten@Tuples[{Tuples[Range[0.25, 0.75, 0.25], 1], 
      Tuples[Range[0, 0.75, 0.25], 4], 
      Tuples[Range[0, Pi/3, Pi/12], 4]}];
```

Please use this code instead of the first. With this code condition 1 is implicitly given. Any other suggestions for building the list is welcomed.  I also added some extra conditions to limit the length of this list.     d

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Indeed I used a step of 0.25 because I knew it was too slow for testing. I will have to change the step once the code is done, so I would have values much closer to the zero. It would be much more efficient to write down the list directly selected, that would be really  perfect!

Comment: @MirkoAveta, yes, I would definitely go with defining the lists you want upfront. For the more complicated cases, I would probably just use `Table` with 9 explicit indexes and integer ranges, and then divide in the end by the appropriate integer.  For example, `Table[{x1,x2,x3,...x9},{x1,0,5},{x2...}]` then divide by `5*9` in this case....